# Unknown host 'repo.maven.apache.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

I have the above issue when I try to build my react native application using android studio
my Gradle version:6.3
I tried to update the Gradle version and set the proxy to auto in android studio but still stuck in the same issue,

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling auto detect proxy in Setting > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Https Settings
I faced the same error today and found that doing the above fixes it